# Why getchar() is taking only one input

Tags: c, getchar

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
char c,d;
c=getchar();
d=getchar();
printf("%c   %c",c,d);
return 0;}
```

here i asked for 2 inputs but it is stopping after taking one input. I mean if i write only one character and press enter it is just showing only that character. Not asking any further inputs.

[image]

But when i am giving two inputs at the same time and then press enter it is showing both.

[image]

Comment: getchar takes 'enter' also as a character. Every key you press will be considered as an input by getchar. In first case its printing 'c' and a new line '\n' whereas in 2nd case its printing both characters.

Comment: For line-based input, I recommend that you always use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Anything else is confusing. However, you may want to [remove the newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471) when using that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, `getchar()` is taking a single character that is typed.  But if you type `c` followed by `enter` you're actually giving it 2, with the second one being the `enter`.  Thus, the second `getchar()` is actually receiving the `enter` key and hence you see the extra blank line in your top output.